# Swift warnings in button action function

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set the signup button so that when the user taps the signup button it will read the read user email and the user password.  So I entered this code to declare my variables  but Swift keeps giving me this warning:> "initialization of immutable value 'userEmail' was never used, consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it." for all the variables/Constant I try to enter.

code:

@IBAction func SignupButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

```
let userEmail = userEmailTextfield.text;
let userUsername = userUsernameTextfield.text;
let userPassword = userPasswordTextfield.text;
```

Below is an image view of the problem.

[image]

Comment: You should include your code in your question rather than in an image, but what do you mean "Swift won't let you"?  You have warnings because you are creating constants but never using them

Comment: Ok, how do I fix the issue? I am trying to declare the constants so that when the signupButton is Tapped it will read e-mail, username,password.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear.

> initialization of immutable value 'userEmail' **was never used**.

The warning goes away when you're going to write code for the to-do line

`// Store Data`

for example by comparing a string with the constant or assigning it to something.